# How to make that only one page requires .htaccess auth?

Tags: .htaccess

Here is my problem. I have one page www.example.com which I don't want to be publicly accessible, so I want to have it behind some kind login.

The problem is that I also have www.example.com/api which I need to be publicly accessible.

Do you have any ideas how to achieve this?

Best regards,
Mladjo

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess (or the `<DIRECTORY>` directive) applies to the directory you put it in (.htaccess) or the directory you specify (`<DIRECTORY>` directive), and all sub-directories below that one.  If you have a specific file that you wish to control access on, put it in its own directory one level deeper than your web-root directory, and apply your access restriction to that path and its subdirs only.

Comment: Problem is that project is written in CakePHP, so every call to pages goes through index.php in webroot.

Comment: Then your PHP script will have to do its own authentication; track an identifiable and unique cookie, link it to a session on the server side.  No cookie, or a cookie pertaining to a client who shouldn't be authorized, the PHP script will have to detect that and not render the page.